# How can I make a parameter vector local for each Kernel in Cuda

Tags: c, nvidia, cuda

How can i make a parameter vector treated as a local variable in each instance in cuda?

```
__global__ void kern(char *text, int N){
//if i change text[0]='0'; the change only affects the current instance of the kernel and not the other threads
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does ```N``` signify?  The length of each array?

Comment: Do you access all elements of text per block? How is your kernel configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every thread will receive the same input parameters, so in this case `char *text` is the same in every thread - that's a fundamental part of the programming model. Since the pointer points to global memory, if one thread changes data through the pointer (i.e. modifies the global memory) then the change affects all threads (ignoring hazards).

This is exactly the same as standard C, except now you have multiple threads accessing through the pointer. In other words, if you modify text[0] inside a standard C function then the changes are visible outside the function.

If I understand correctly, you're asking for every thread to have a local copy of the contents of `text`. Well the solution is exactly the same as for standard C if you don't want changes visible outside the function:

```
__global__ void kern(char* text, int N) {
    // If you have an upper bound for N...
    char localtext[NMAX];
    // If you don't know the range of N...
    char *localtext;
    localtext = malloc(N*sizeof(char));

    // Copy from text to localtext
    // Since each thread has the same value for i this will
    // broadcast from the L1 cache
    for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        localtext[i] = text[i];

    //...
}
```

Note that I'm assuming you have sm_20 or later. Also note that while using malloc in device code is possible, you will pay a performance price.

Comment: You can not call a host function inside a kernel. Your approach should be done using shared memory

Comment: @pQB: in-kernel malloc is supported on Fermi, which is exactly what was pointed out in the answer: 'Note that I'm assuming you have sm_20 or later'

Comment: Tom: My apologies. I though faster than i read. @talonmies: Thanks you for the review